# unexpected token ':'.parse - React native Android

Tags: android, react-native

[image: unexpected token ':'.parse error]

When I run the app in **Android 6.0.1 development mode** it works fine and when I convert to development build it **throws unexpected token ':'.parse error** as shown in the picture. And then I tried with **Android Pie** OS with development mode and it throws same error. Was bit confusing about what goes wrong

This is my build script

```
    buildscript {
    ext {
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.0.1"
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "16.0.1"
        firebaseVersion = "17.0.1"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
        // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2' // <--- use this version or newer
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' // <--- use this version or newer
    }
}
```

My React native version is **"0.59.9"**

I guess I reached to some extent, It is an exception thrown at **super.dispatchMessage(msg)**

```
package com.facebook.react.bridge.queue;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;

public class MessageQueueThreadHandler extends Handler {

  private final QueueThreadExceptionHandler mExceptionHandler;

  public MessageQueueThreadHandler(Looper looper, QueueThreadExceptionHandler exceptionHandler) {
    super(looper);
    mExceptionHandler = exceptionHandler;
  }

  @Override
  public void dispatchMessage(Message msg) {
    try {
      super.dispatchMessage(msg);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      mExceptionHandler.handleException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Now If I print and check what comes as msg I Guess I can reach the problem.. When I edit this file, my changes are not getting reflected when I run **react-native run-android** Is there any way to print that msg and check it??

Guys no idea yet???

**Update-1**

I am sure something was wrong with one of my modules, because I just change the entry file(App.js) to

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';

export default class HelloWorldApp extends Component {
    async componentDidMount() {
        SplashScreen.hide();
    }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <Text>Hello, world!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Even then got the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

Rather than applying style directly, follow below structure

```
 render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.style}>
        <Text>Hello, world!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
   style: {
      flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center"
   }
});
```